# LINQ to DataTable query

Tags: .net, linq

I have such DataTable, which I am trying to query.

```
ID|Language
sfd2133 English
asd213d English
vgjj31j English
fvjfjf2 German
dac31e3 English
asaq213 French
dent231 French
1dedae3 German
```

I manage to get single Language:

```
        IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> ids=
            from asset in selectedItems.AsEnumerable()
            select new Tuple<string, string>(asset["ID"].ToString(), 
            asset["Language"].ToString());
```

How do I get `IEnumerable<List<Tuple<string, string>>` where `List<Tuple<string,string>>` is collections of ID's and Single market, say French only.

Comment: Do you want to group them with language?

Comment: Why don't you use a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<String>>` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really want to achieve. The easiest way to get a `List` instead of `IEnumerable` is using `ToList()` extension method:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> ids=
            (from asset in selectedItems.AsEnumerable()
            select new Tuple<string, string>(asset["ID"].ToString(), 
            asset["Language"].ToString())).ToList();
```

If you want to get `IEnumerable<List<>>` where each list contains only rows for single Language, you can use grouping syntax:

```
IEnumerable<List<Tuple<string, string>>> ids=
            from asset in selectedItems.AsEnumerable()
            group asset by asset["Language"].ToString() into g
            select g.Select(i => new Tuple<string, string>(i["ID"].ToString(), 
            i["Language"].ToString())).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, amazing answer! Dzien kuje : - )))

Answer (score 2):

So you want to group by the language.

Why don't you use a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<String>>` instead?

```
Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<String>> DialogResult =
            selectedItems.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Language"))
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("ID")));
```

The key is the language and the value is an `IEnumerable<String>` of the appropriate IDs.

If you for example want to list all IDs for *English*, you would do:

```
var englishIDs = DialogResult["English"];
String output = string.Join(", ", englishIDs); // sfd2133, asd213d, vgjj31j, dac31e3
```

`Dictionaries` have the best lookup performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
Hello try with (Essaye avec ce code Wild)

(from asset in selectedItems.AsEnumerable()

select new
{
   ID= asset.Field<String>("ID"),
   Language= asset.Field<String>("Language")
})
.AsEnumerable()
.ToDictionary(k => k.ID, v => v.Language);
```

Comment: This doesn't work since a Dictionary cannot contain duplicate keys and you don't group by the Language.